# Download a SlideShare presentation as a PowerPoint file

Tags: slideshare

I am trying to download a SlideShare presentation that I liked. I registered on the SlideShare site, but the download only gives me the PDF version.

Is there a way I could download the PPT version (Microsoft PowerPoint) of the same presentation?

Answer (score 2):

SlideShare will give the original format of that particular presentation at the time of downloading.
It would be possible that the original content is in pdf format.